# What is the Purpose of Augmented Grammar in LR parsers?

Tags: compilers, parsers

I was reading the LR() parsers from the Dragon Book where I came across these lines:

> To construct canonical LR(0) collection for a grammar, we define an
>   **augmented grammar** and 2 functions, CLOSURE and GOTO.

for example say if we have a grammar like-->

S → BB
B → cB/d

Then in augmented grammar we define it as

S' → S

S → BB

B → cB/d

In the dragon book the reason for this is mentioned as,

> The purpose of this new starting state production is to indicate the
>   parser when it should stop parsing and announce the acceptance of the
>   input. That is acceptance occurs when only when the parser is about to
>   reduce S' → S

I am unable to understand what this even means and how this augmented grammar is useful for parsing. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't understand what that means I'd suggest going back in the book and re-read every section you don't fully understand. I think the books explanation is clear and I couldn't say it better myself.

Comment: @yuval any answer from u will be very helpful, as you can explain topics in a fluid manner.

Answer (score 3):

The augmented grammar adds a new starting non-terminal $S'$ with the sole production $S' \to S$. This helps in detecting acceptance: If you reduce by this particular production (to the non-terminal $S'$), you are accepting. To reduce to the start non-terminal of the original grammar tells you nothing, it might appear on some right hand side.